# Get first id according to condition from SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not good in understanding of SQL can you point me to what am I doing wrong? 
I have a DB with user activity. I want to do some statistic and I want to know the ID of first activity that have done user if status is done. 
Table activity; row: ID, user_id, status... status can be `0` for fail and `1` for done. Can someone point me how to do it correct because when I do this :

```
SELECT MIN(activity.ID)
FROM activity 
WHERE activity.status=1
GROUP BY activity.username
```

I will get the ID of first activities that where first not done for user, but I need just if it was first activity in general and it was not done. 
Next think I try to do is select from select but I can't do it right or I need a joint maybe.

```
 SELECT  activity.ID
   FROM ( SELECT MIN(ID) FROM activity GROUP BY username ) a
   WHERE ID.a=activity.ID AND activity.status=1
```

I think I do something rely wrong in SQL logic, can someone point me to what is good logic for this kind of query. Tx. in advance.

```
More exact what I need
```

I need all id of activity that was first not done task of users, like in this table is stored all activity in general from all users. Example of output

```
Table activity 
ID    USER_id      Status 
0     001           0
1     001           1
2     002           1
3     002           1
4     004           1
5     003           0
6     003           0
7     003           1
8     004           1
9     004           0
10    001           1
```

What I want for output is ID: 2,4

Comment: Question is not clear, Please can you give some sample data or a fiddle to understand the question and required output?

Comment: I just want to make a statistic report, for this I need ID of all activity that was first for user and not done in the same time. Because I know how to do first not done or first ID for user in general

Comment: What do you mean by first not done?

Comment: Do you need a count of rows per user where status = 1?

Comment: I want to select the ID of the all tasks, just in case if it much 2 conditions, it is first task for  user, and it is not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select id from activity 
where status = 1 and id in 
(select id from activity group by user_id)
```

Subquery gives you id of the 1st activity for the user, rest the outer query will do it for you.
Hope this solves the problem!

Comment: Check the add to question, I want all users that have first activity status 1

Comment: I don't want ID 1, because on ID '0' the is the same user and it have status 0, so it don't mach condition first activity of user with status 1

Comment: Check the edit. This will give you the proper result

Comment: I am doing manual testing now. in some minutest will let you know, slow DB :(

Comment: I don't understand it until the end but manual testing show that is working, have done manual testing for first 20 users. tx a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150596/discussion-between-shuddh-and-alexei).

Answer (score 1):

your question is not full clear but if you want to first id where status = 1 then use this sql which help you and must your id need to primary key

```
SELECT min(ID) FROM activity WHERE status =1 GROUP BY  USER_id ORDER BY min(ID) asc;
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I just add more specific, if it would be so easy I wont got here :(

Comment: Look up I added some more specific request in order to be more clear

Comment: can you give any demo output?

Comment: you want output if user have 2 entry with status 1 then first id?

Comment: no, just ID that have to much 2 conditions. first it have to be first ID of any user in table second. it have to have status 1

Comment: I just tested your answer, it actually give the first note done (status=1) activity from users, so not good, because even if user have first activity status 0, it will show me it in output with the ID of the activity of the next task witch have status 1, so it the same what I have until now, but different done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150588/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-alexei).

Comment: hello , i am not full understand your requirement

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find what's the first operation for each user:

```
select min(id) user_id 
 from activity 
 group by user_id
```

Once you have that, you determine if it was successful and list only the successful users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
  FROM activity 
  JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) user_id 
    FROM activity 
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) t_id USING (user_id)
 WHERE 
  status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by [@Shuddh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3345454/shuddh) is good, but I found a solution how to optimize it.

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `activity` 
JOIN (SELECT `id` FROM activity GROUP BY `user_id`) `a` ON `user_id`=`a`.user_id  
WHERE `status` = 1
```

As I understand according to some articles the joint will do it faster. And it is faster on my DB, from 40s to 15s.